# parsing a deeply nested JSON data present in a .dms file

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to parse a deeply nested json data which is saved as .dms file. I saved some transactions of the file as a .json file. When I try json.load() function to read the .json file. I am getting the error as

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 4392)
```

Opening the .dms file in text editor, I copied 3 transactions from it and saved it as .json file. The transactions in the file are not separated by commas. It is separated by new lines. When I used 1 transaction of it as a .json file and used json.load() function, it successfully read. But when I try the json file with 3 transactions, its showing error.

```
import json
d = json.load(open('t3.json')) or 

with open('t3.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

the example transaction is :

```
{  
   "header":{  
      "msgType":"SOURCE_EVENT",

   },
   "content":{  
      "txntype":"ums",
      "ISSUE":{  
         "REQUEST":{  
            "messageTime":"2019-06-06 21:54:11.492",
            "Code":"655400",

         },
         "RESPONSE":{  
            "Time":"2019-06-06 21:54:11.579",

         }
      },
      "DATA":{  
         "UserId":"021",

      },
{header:{.....}}}


{header:{......}}}
```

This is how my json data from an API looks like. I wrote it in a readable way. But its all continuously written and whenever a header starts it starts from a new line. and the .dms file has 3500 transactions. the two transactions are not even seperated by commas. Its separated by new lines. But within a transaction there are extra spaces in a value. for eg; "company": "Target   Chips  123 CA"

The output I need:
I need to make a csv by extracting values of keys messageType, messageTime, userid from the data for each transaction.

Please help out to clear the error and suggest ways to extract the data I need from these transactions for every transaction and put in .csv file for me to do further analysis and machine learning modeling.

Comment: Is there exactly one object in each line? Your example shows the first object spread over multiple lines, is that just because you formatted it for us?

Comment: yes @Alex, one object in one line. I wrote over multiple lines here to tell you how deep it is. It is actually like 
{header:{....}}}

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481557/how-can-one-create-a-python-dictionary-key-value-from-select-objects-in-a-js .

Comment: @AlexHall I understood getting the attributes I need inside the json object. But what about my error while reading the file
{header:{....}}}}

{header:{....}}}}

{header:{....}}}}

My json objects in the file are separated by new line and its looks like above. and yeah each object is continuously spread out for a couple of lines as its of 100 lines each. But the each new json object (eg:   {header:{..) starts in a new line
Can you please help out with the "jsondecode error" its talking about. Im not able to share a screenshot here. otherwise, the error could be explained clearly

Answer (score 0):

If each object is contained within a single line, then read one line at a time and decode each line separately:

```
with open(fileName, 'r') as file_to_read:
    for line in filetoread:
        json_line = json.loads(line)
```

If objects are spread over multiple lines, then ideally try and fix the source of the data, otherwise use my library [jsonfinder](https://github.com/alexmojaki/jsonfinder). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687015/2482744) is an example answer that may help.